# Automate combining 2 picture and adding logo without photoshop

Tags: automation, batch-processing

What I would like to achieve is for someone to be able to input 2 pictures, which would be center-cropped and stretched to 100% height of the new composition.
Also to have a logo added to the same place every time. The logo should have transparency.

Is there a way to do this without using photoshop. Maybe some kind of php page which the user could upload the pictures to which would then spit out the result?

I've attached a VERY crude drawing of what I mean...[image]

Comment: This is more of a programming question (or "how do I find a service that does this already").

Comment: You can use another programmable platform that can take, crop, resize and position your images and then output the result. Microsoft Execel is one of them, OpenOffice stuff is another and it's freeware. The hard part is to learn to make the script.

Answer (score 1):

Use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) its pretty much the tool for this kind of thing. [Cropping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/), [scaling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) and [layering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/) is pretty easy, you can find bindings to php, python, etc too if you don't want to use the cmd.

The only bit that is problematic is finding where the interesting bit actually lies. This is all fine if you take the pictures yourself, or have instructed how to take the pictures (which is fine for games events). But if you need to find the center of interest from random pictures then that is a different question. But for that you can use something like [facedetect](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/facedetect/).

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend learning about actions and scripts! You will first have to crop making sure your subject is scaled proportionally or otherwise aesthetic. If all photos were shot the same you could batch apply this crop, or just do them all at once/per diem. Then, moving on to recording the layout action. I think you could record yourself masking one side, then the other, per your grid, and adding the logo/symbol.

...... thanks for the simple and intuitive ui, adobe! lol

anyway here's a product/cheatsheet/modernized fix for many social media sizing woes! http://sproutsocial.com/landscape

Comment: What do "social media sizing woes" have to do with the question?